# Swift: Func variable

Tags: ios, xcode, function, variables, swift

There is variable `playBegin` in a different class, that activates after a countdown. Once the countdown is over, `playBegin` becomes true. I was wondering how to create **a function that begins once playBegin becomes true**.

```
when playBegin becomes true {
func-y stuff goes on here
}
```

This function occurs in a different file than in the one that the var is set so it would be important for the func to recognise this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Look into property observers and notifications, or key-value observing

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_390

Answer (score 1):

You can use *property observer*:

```
var playBegin = false {
  didSet {
    if playBegin {
      // the code to execute when the variable becomes true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: should I put this in a class, a struct? or what else?

Comment: @WilliamClark put it in a class. It will also work in structs.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a change with playBegin - I think this is to do with the fact that it can't recognise my variable from another class